# Right align list item

Tags: html, css

This is probably a simple question but I am struggling. I think it has to do with floats but I am getting confused if I can to clear the float or left align the remaining items.

How do I get the "login" list item to sit on the right, with everything else sitting on the left?

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/kYfNB/21/

My html is here:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header" class="inner">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Admin</a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="jobs.html">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="sites.html">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="feeds.html">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="feeds.html">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="inner">
     <h1>Add</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since login is the last item, you could use [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) to float the last `li` element to the right.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e734N/)

```
#header ul li:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

This would however require you to remove the float on the `#header ul`. Change:

```
#header h1, #header ul, #header ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

to:

```
#header h1, #header ul li {
    float:left;
}
```